# Explanation of Laurent Series

Tags: laurent-series

In this pdf: http://sym.lboro.ac.uk/resources/Handout-Laurent.pdf, it says that 
$$\frac{1}{1-z} = \begin{cases} \displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n, & |z|<1 \\ -\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n}, & |z|>1 \end{cases}$$
I know how they get the first one, but how do you get $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n}, |z|>1$? 
Given this information, how do we find the Laurent Series of something like $\frac{1}{n^3(n+1)^3}$ or $\frac{1}{(n+1)^5}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second: if $\lvert z\rvert > 1$, then
$$
\frac{1}{1-z}= -\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{z}}
= -\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^n
= -\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n}
$$
using the first result applied to $x\stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{1}{z}$, since $\lvert x\rvert < 1$. Note that the index in the rightmost sum starts at $1$, not $0$.

---

As an application, let us look at $\frac{1}{n^3(n+1)^3}$. We can write
$$
\frac{1}{n^3(n+1)^3} = \frac{1}{n^6}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^3}.
$$
Recall that $$
\frac{2}{(1+z)^3} = \frac{d^2}{dz^2}\frac{1}{1+z}
= \frac{d^2}{dz^2}\frac{1}{1-(-z)}
$$
so that, as long as $\lvert z\rvert < 1$, we have by properties of power series within their radius of convergence
Recall that $$\begin{align*}
\frac{2}{(1+z)^3} &= \frac{d^2}{dz^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k z^k
 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{d^2}{dz^2}  z^k
 = \sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k k(k-1) z^{k-2}
\\&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+2} (k+2)(k+1) z^k
\end{align*}$$
so that
$$
\frac{1}{n^3(n+1)^3} = \frac{1}{2n^6}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+2} (k+2)(k+1) \frac{1}{n^k}.
$$

Comment: Could you please answer the 2 example questions that I have listed above?

Comment: @D.R. Like that -- does it seem to be what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you. If it isn't too much trouble, can you do the quintic as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @D.R. I suggest you try, as an exercise -- this will involve differentiating the original expression 5 times, but the idea is the same. (I can have a look afterwards if you want.)